# How to render elements inside a particular div in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of dropdowns rendered.

```
<ul>
  <li id="list_1">
    <select>
      <option>---</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li id="list_2">
    <select>
      <option>---</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

On selecting the **option** from the dropdown.I render a **span** element with an **onClick** method binded to it and a **div** element as shown below.

```
<ul>
  <li id="list_1">
    <select>
     <option>---</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <span onClick={this.getDropdown}> (+) </span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li id="list_2">
    <select>
      <option>---</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <span onClick={this.getDropdown}> (+) </span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> **Result 1:** 
>   if **option with value 1** was selected from the first dropdown and **(+)** is clicked from **li element with id="list_1"**.I must get the result as shown below.

```
<ul>
  <li id="list_1">
    <select>
     <option>---</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <span onClick={this.getDropdown}> (+) </span>
    <div>
         <select>
            <option>---</option>
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
         </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="list_2">
    <select>
      <option>---</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <span onClick={this.getDropdown}> (+) </span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> **Result 2:**
>   if **option with value 5** was selected from the second dropdown and **(+)** is clicked from **li element with id="list_2"**.I must get the result as shown below.

```
<ul>
  <li id="list_1">
    <select>
     <option>---</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <span onClick={this.getDropdown}> (+) </span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li id="list_2">
    <select>
      <option>---</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <span onClick={this.getDropdown}> (+) </span>
    <div>
       <select>
          <option>---</option>
          <option>X</option>
          <option>Y</option>
          <option>Z</option>
       </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> **NOTE:** **li** id values were added only for reference.**li** elements have no **id's**.
>
> The problem is when rendering components we have to explicitly mention were the elements have to be rendered.Like `ReactDOM.render("<App/>",document.getElementById("container"))` .Here the `<div>` in which the dropdown is rendered doesn't have any **id**.So If I add an id to the `<div id="container"></div>`.The dropdown is overwritten.

Comment: So what part exactly is working in your code, and what part isn't? You want the `div` containing the `select` element to be rendered **each** time the user presses (+)? Are the values always `A` and `B` in the generated `select`? You need to explain better.

Comment: @Chris The problem is when rendering components we have to explicitly mention were the elements have to be rendered.Like `ReactDOM.render("<App/>",document.getElementById("container"))` .Here the `<div>` in which the dropdown is rendered doesn't have any **id**.So If I add an id to the `<div id="container"></div>`.The dropdown is overwritten

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from dropdown, and return different views based on it like:

```
render: function(){
  this.state.dropdown? return(//render with no dropdown) : return(//render with dropdown.)
}
```